# $V$ be a vector space , $T:V \to V$ be a linear operator , then is $\ker (T) \cap R(T) \cong R(T)/R(T^2) $?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a vector space , $T:V \to V$ be a linear operator , then is it true that

$\ker (T) \cap R(T) \cong R(T)/R(T^2) $ ( where $R(T)$ denotes the range of $T$ ) ?

I know that the statement is true when $V$ is finite dimensional as I can show that if $V$ is finite

dimensional , then $\dim (\ker (T) \cap R(T))=rank (T) - rank (T^2)=\dim R(T)/R(T^2)$ ,

but I don't know what happens in general . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to hold in the infinite-dimensional setting.  Let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ (where $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and we denote members of this set by functions $x:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$), and define the left-shift operator $S_L\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ by
$S_L(x)(n)=x(n+1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Then
\begin{align*}
R(S_L)&=R(S_L^2)=\ell^2(\mathbb{N}), \\
\ker(S_L)&= \{x\in\ell^2(\mathbb{N}):x(n)=0\  \forall n\geq2\} = \ker(S_L)\cap R(S_L).
\end{align*}
Thus $R(S_L)/R(S_L^2)\cong \{0\}$, while $\ker(S_L)\cap R(S_L)\cong\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: you appear to be right ... though I just realized your example doesn't violate $(\ker(T) \cap R(T) ) \times R(T^2) \cong R(T)$ which holds in finite dimensional case due to the same formula I mentioned . Do you have any thoughts on this later isomorphism claim ?

Comment: That I will have to think about.  Good questions!

Comment: thanks , your example motivated me to ask if there is any possible way out ( I am not very optimistic though :p)

Comment: I have more faith about this next claim, but it may take a while as I am getting very tired (its nearly 1:00a.m. local).

Comment: Okay no problem :) I will ask a different question with linking this question ...

Comment: Did you take a look at the linked question ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867250/v-be-a-vector-space-tv-to-v-be-a-linear-operator-then-is-kert-ca?noredirect=1&lq=1 ....