# $V$ be a vector space , $T:V \to V$ be a linear operator , then is $(\ker(T) \cap R(T) ) \times R(T^2) \cong R(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a vector space , $T:V \to V$ be a linear operator , then is it true that

$(\ker(T) \cap R(T) ) \times R(T^2) \cong R(T)$ ?

(note that the direct product is well-defined as both the spaces are subspaces of $V$ so have same ground field )

See [$V$ be a vector space , $T:V \to V$ be a linear operator , then is $\ker (T) \cap R(T) \cong R(T)/R(T^2) $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867207/v-be-a-vector-space-tv-to-v-be-a-linear-operator-then-is-ker-t-ca)    , note that the isomorphism holds when $V$ is finite dimensional as it is known that if $U,W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over  a same field , then $\dim (U \times W)=\dim U + \dim W$ . Also note that the example given in the linked question doesn't violate the stated isomorphism here . Please help . Thanks in advance .

EDIT : One general thing that can be noted is that $R(T)/R(T)\cap \ker (T) \cong R(T^2)$ holds , but I don't know whether it can be used to prove or disprove the claim in question

NOTE : If $V,W$ are vector spaces over a field $F$ then $V \times W$ is a vector space with  addition and  multiplication defined as $(v,w)+(v',w'):=(v+v',w+w') $ ; $ k.(v,w):=(kv,kw)$ . It can be seen that if $B_V , B_W$ are bases for $V , W$ repectively , then $(B_V \times \{O_W\})\cup (\{O_V\}\times B_W)$ is a basis for $V \times W$ , so that if $V,W$ are finite dimensional then so is $V \times W$ and

$\dim (V \times W)=|(B_V \times \{O_W\}) \cup (\{O_V\}\times B_W)|=|B_V \times \{O_W\}|+|\{O_V\}\times B_W|=|B_V|+|B_W|=\dim V + \dim W$

So this "direct product" is substantially different from "direct sum"

Comment: If by "direct product" here you mean "direct sum", then you first would have to prove $\;\left(\ker T\cap R(T)\right)\cap R(T^2)=\{0\}\;$ in order to even have a direct sums here (I guess $\;R(T)=\text{Im}\,T=$ the image of $\;T\;$). If you meant other thing please do define.

Comment: Assuming you do mean the sum of the two subspaces, then the answer is no. Consider $T\colon\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ defined by $T(x,y,z) = (0,x,y)$; then ker$(T)$ and $R(T^2)$ both equal $(0,0,\Bbb R)$. (Note, by the way, that the first iteration of $T$ isn't really used in this proposed statement: If we set $W=R(T)$ and $T_1=T|_W$, then the assertion is equivalent to ker$(T_1) \times R(T_1) \cong W$.)

Comment: @DonAntonio , Greg Martin : I have edited . Please take a look

Comment: @DonAntonio : Hello , you there ... ?

Comment: @GregMartin : Please see my edit

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. So does the following argument work? Take any basis $B_1$ for $R(T) \cap{}$ker$(T)$; extend it to a basis $B$ for $R(T)$. Then map the basis $B$ to $R(T^2)$ using the given isomorphism. The image of $B\setminus B_1$ should be a basis for $R(T^2)$. Then your desired isomorphism follows by dimension-counting (which is to say, counting cardinalities of bases).